# CSS Navbar style

Tags: html, css

I've just started studying  HTML & CSS, I'm trying to format a menu for a website

I can't figure out why the orange box in the menu (when the mouse is over the element) has a gap at the top

Here's my code:

```
.navbar ul{
  float:right;
  list-style: none;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding:  15px;  
}

.navbar ul li{
  display: inline-block;
 
}
.navbar ul li a{
  display:block; 
  text-align:center;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 0 70px 20px;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do[image]

Here's the HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Information</title>
  <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class= "navbar">
    <a href="info.html" class = "nav-logo">Theme Park</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tickets</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Plan Your Visit</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.</p>
      <button class="btns">More</button>
      <button class="btns">Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="photo1.jpeg">
    </div>
  </main>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML too?

Comment: CSS without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please get in the habit of providing a proper [mre] of your issue, when you are asking these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `padding` and `margin` for the `ul` to `0` and apply appropriate `padding` to the `a` (or `li`) elements. That way the nav items (`a`) will be as high as their `ul` container, with their background color extending across the full height.

(I added a background-color to the `ul` to make it more obvious)

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
.navbar ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.content {
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="info.html" class="nav-logo">Theme Park</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tickets</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Plan Your Visit</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.</p>
    <button class="btns">More</button>
    <button class="btns">Buy Now</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="photo1.jpeg">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time!!